# is there a python function to create an alertindex in elastic

Tags: python, elasticsearch, indexing, alert

I need help to write a python function script to create alert when the data below is sent to elastic to compare the previous and present day data if its 0 or 20% difference , it should give an alert

```py
def alertindexes(data):
   print(data)
data = [{'indexname': 'awsbill-octopusenabled*', 'presentday': 301, 'previousday': 301}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-octopusrole*', 'presentday': 335, 'previousday': 334}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-usernrole*', 'presentday': 279, 'previousday': 279}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-gc-rbac*', 'presentday': 3914, 'previousday': 3917}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-awsallusernrole*', 'presentday': 235, 'previousday': 234}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_ec2volupd*', 'presentday': 31911, 'previousday': 32010}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-predicted-ec2vol*', 'presentday': 5649, 'previousday': 4826}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-isdsaws-accounts*', 'presentday': 6026, 'previousday': 6026}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-users-account-info*', 'presentday': 11236, 'previousday': 11222}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-config*', 'presentday': 101736, 'previousday': 101808}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-budgets*', 'presentday': 568, 'previousday': 568}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-cases*', 'presentday': 35, 'previousday': 36}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-cost-usage*', 'presentday': 11279, 'previousday': 11654}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_s3_metrics_bsize*', 'presentday': 698, 'previousday': 698}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_s3api_list_objects*', 'presentday': 954, 'previousday': 954}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_s3api_object_versions*', 'presentday': 954, 'previousday': 954}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-ec2*', 'presentday': 11963, 'previousday': 12260}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_ec2upd*', 'presentday': 9092, 'previousday': 9300}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-elasticcache*', 'presentday': 241, 'previousday': 241}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-iam-policies*', 'presentday': 5244, 'previousday': 5239}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-iam-roles*', 'presentday': 49473, 'previousday': 49468}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-images*', 'presentday': 571712, 'previousday': 572146}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-kms*', 'presentday': 9373, 'previousday': 9301}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-rds*', 'presentday': 2294, 'previousday': 2280}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_rdsupd*', 'presentday': 2294, 'previousday': 2280}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-s3*', 'presentday': 4563, 'previousday': 4555}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-ssm*', 'presentday': 122475, 'previousday': 122475}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-support*', 'presentday': 12458, 'previousday': 12562}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-vol*', 'presentday': 39673, 'previousday': 39723}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_ctrail*', 'presentday': 189, 'previousday': 268}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-health*', 'presentday': 66583, 'previousday': 65313}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_costusage*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 14120}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_eks_cluster*', 'presentday': 111, 'previousday': 111}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_eks_nodes*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_eks_namespaces*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_eks_pods*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-grand-central*', 'presentday': 6026, 'previousday': 6026}, {'indexname': 'gcpbill_disks*', 'presentday': 14, 'previousday': 14}, {'indexname': 'gcpbill_iam_roles*', 'presentday': 1097, 'previousday': 1097}, {'indexname': 'gcpbill_instances*', 'presentday': 4, 'previousday': 4}, {'indexname': 'agg-awsbill-cwperc-cpuutilization-v2*', 'presentday': 6848, 'previousday': 6640}, {'indexname': 'agg-awsbill-cwperc-mem-cached-v2*', 'presentday': 5866, 'previousday': 5256}, {'indexname': 'agg-awsbill-cwperc-mem-total-v2*', 'presentday': 2322, 'previousday': 2859}, {'indexname': 'agg-awsbill-cwperc-mem-used-v2*', 'presentday': 462, 'previousday': 882}, {'indexname': 'agg-awsbill-cwperc-volumereadops*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}, {'indexname': 'agg-awsbill-cwperc-volumewriteops*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}, {'indexname': 'rollup-awsbill-cwperc-cpuutilization-p99-v2*', 'presentday': 11593, 'previousday': 11423}, {'indexname': 'rollup-awsbill-cwperc-mem-cached-p99-v2*', 'presentday': 5355, 'previousday': 5260}, {'indexname': 'rollup-awsbill-cwperc-mem-total-p99-v2*', 'presentday': 2163, 'previousday': 2094}, {'indexname': 'rollup-awsbill-cwperc-mem-used-p99-v2*', 'presentday': 871, 'previousday': 871}, {'indexname': 'rollup-awsbill-cwvol-volumereadops-v3*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}, {'indexname': 'rollup-awsbill-cwvol-awsbill_cwvol_volumewriteops-v3*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}]
indexda = alertindexes(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right track and just need to add some logical checks.

The data itself contain a list of dicts, so i show the example for the first dict (at index=0).

both `presentday` and `previousday` seem to appear in each dict, so if you wanted to test for each one, then you would do a `for loop` or `list comprehension`.

```py
data = [{'indexname': 'awsbill-octopusenabled*', 'presentday': 301, 'previousday': 301}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-octopusrole*', 'presentday': 335, 'previousday': 334}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-usernrole*', 'presentday': 279, 'previousday': 279}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-gc-rbac*', 'presentday': 3914, 'previousday': 3917}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-awsallusernrole*', 'presentday': 235, 'previousday': 234}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_ec2volupd*', 'presentday': 31911, 'previousday': 32010}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-predicted-ec2vol*', 'presentday': 5649, 'previousday': 4826}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-isdsaws-accounts*', 'presentday': 6026, 'previousday': 6026}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-users-account-info*', 'presentday': 11236, 'previousday': 11222}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-config*', 'presentday': 101736, 'previousday': 101808}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-budgets*', 'presentday': 568, 'previousday': 568}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-cases*', 'presentday': 35, 'previousday': 36}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-cost-usage*', 'presentday': 11279, 'previousday': 11654}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_s3_metrics_bsize*', 'presentday': 698, 'previousday': 698}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_s3api_list_objects*', 'presentday': 954, 'previousday': 954}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_s3api_object_versions*', 'presentday': 954, 'previousday': 954}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-ec2*', 'presentday': 11963, 'previousday': 12260}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_ec2upd*', 'presentday': 9092, 'previousday': 9300}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-elasticcache*', 'presentday': 241, 'previousday': 241}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-iam-policies*', 'presentday': 5244, 'previousday': 5239}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-iam-roles*', 'presentday': 49473, 'previousday': 49468}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-images*', 'presentday': 571712, 'previousday': 572146}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-kms*', 'presentday': 9373, 'previousday': 9301}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-rds*', 'presentday': 2294, 'previousday': 2280}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_rdsupd*', 'presentday': 2294, 'previousday': 2280}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-s3*', 'presentday': 4563, 'previousday': 4555}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-ssm*', 'presentday': 122475, 'previousday': 122475}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-support*', 'presentday': 12458, 'previousday': 12562}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-vol*', 'presentday': 39673, 'previousday': 39723}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_ctrail*', 'presentday': 189, 'previousday': 268}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-health*', 'presentday': 66583, 'previousday': 65313}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_costusage*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 14120}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_eks_cluster*', 'presentday': 111, 'previousday': 111}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_eks_nodes*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_eks_namespaces*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}, {'indexname': 'awsbill_eks_pods*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}, {'indexname': 'awsbill-grand-central*', 'presentday': 6026, 'previousday': 6026}, {'indexname': 'gcpbill_disks*', 'presentday': 14, 'previousday': 14}, {'indexname': 'gcpbill_iam_roles*', 'presentday': 1097, 'previousday': 1097}, {'indexname': 'gcpbill_instances*', 'presentday': 4, 'previousday': 4}, {'indexname': 'agg-awsbill-cwperc-cpuutilization-v2*', 'presentday': 6848, 'previousday': 6640}, {'indexname': 'agg-awsbill-cwperc-mem-cached-v2*', 'presentday': 5866, 'previousday': 5256}, {'indexname': 'agg-awsbill-cwperc-mem-total-v2*', 'presentday': 2322, 'previousday': 2859}, {'indexname': 'agg-awsbill-cwperc-mem-used-v2*', 'presentday': 462, 'previousday': 882}, {'indexname': 'agg-awsbill-cwperc-volumereadops*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}, {'indexname': 'agg-awsbill-cwperc-volumewriteops*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}, {'indexname': 'rollup-awsbill-cwperc-cpuutilization-p99-v2*', 'presentday': 11593, 'previousday': 11423}, {'indexname': 'rollup-awsbill-cwperc-mem-cached-p99-v2*', 'presentday': 5355, 'previousday': 5260}, {'indexname': 'rollup-awsbill-cwperc-mem-total-p99-v2*', 'presentday': 2163, 'previousday': 2094}, {'indexname': 'rollup-awsbill-cwperc-mem-used-p99-v2*', 'presentday': 871, 'previousday': 871}, {'indexname': 'rollup-awsbill-cwvol-volumereadops-v3*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}, {'indexname': 'rollup-awsbill-cwvol-awsbill_cwvol_volumewriteops-v3*', 'presentday': 0, 'previousday': 0}]

def alertindexes(data):
    # do a logic checks
    d = data[0]
    if d['presentday'] == d['previousday']:
        print('present = previous')
        return 1    
    if d['presentday'] >= d['previousday']*1.2:
        print('more than 20%')    
        return 2

indexda = alertindexes(data)
```

result:

```
present = previous
```

EDIT:  (example to loop).

If you want to test each `dict` in the list then you can do something like this:

```
def alertindexes_loop(data):
    
    for d in data:
        # do a logic checks
        
        if d['presentday'] == d['previousday']:
            print('present = previous')
                
        if d['presentday'] >= d['previousday']*1.2:
            print('more than 20%')    

    return 'done'    

indexda = alertindexes_loop(data)
```

Comment: Thank you somuch but if i may , how do i do the for loop incase i want to test for eachone

Comment: Help me with the looping through the indexes above

Comment: you would just do a nested for loop, then you would get many results (one for each dict). I have edited the answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks , i am a work in progress in python

Comment: But what if from this function i wan to a return a list of dictionary which contains index name, present and previous day details?

Comment: that needs to be asked as a different question.  For some reason the answer given has been marked down with no comment or reason why...

Comment: def alertindexes_loop(data):
    
    for d in data:
        # do a logic checks
        
        if d['presentday'] == d['previousday']:
            print('present = previous')
                
        if d['presentday'] >= d['previousday']*1.2:
            print('more than 20%')    

    return 'done'    

indexda = alertindexes_loop(data)   from this function return a list of dictionary which contains index name, present and previous day details…please help